# Hot reloader with create-react-app redux won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux

I have a react redux webapp, I startde with create-react-app, then slowly adapt redux. hot reloading don't reload the entire page and clear my state that's why I'm looking into implementing HMR,
I found a reference here https://medium.com/@brianhan/hot-reloading-cra-without-eject-b54af352c642, but no luck with my codes below.
No error but when I change the reducer states, the entire page got reloaded.

my index.js code

```
import configureStore from './store'

const store = configureStore()
const render = App => {
  return ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
}

render(App)

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    const NextApp = require('./App').default
    render(NextApp)
  })
}
```

my store code

```
import rootReducers from './reducers'

const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducers,
    composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware
      )
    )
  )

  if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ||
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'staging'
  ) {
    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
        store.replaceReducer(rootReducers)
      })
    }
  }

  return store
}

export default configureStore
```

Comment: After spending the last 48 hours building a hot loader boilerplate, I can say that RHL/HMR is pretty dang buggy, especially when handling/showing errors and refreshing. If you want, you can fork it and give it a test drive to see if hot loading is worth it: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate. Otherwise, I'd recommend sticking with the CRA as is.

Comment: @mattcarlotta CRA doesn't have hot reload for redux